# Current date to insert in mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this below code i have placed controller and model i insert firstname ,lastname,email address ,username ,password and date .But i cant insert my current date to mysql pls help to solve the issue.

Controller:login

```
function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('membership_model');

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');           
            }
        }
```

model:membership_model

```
function create_member()
    {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'date' => $this->input->post('date','curdate()'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                       
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
                {
                echo"<script>alert('This value already exists');</script>";
                }
                if ($this->db->_error_number() == "")
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('create', 'create');
                }

        return $insert;
    }



function curdate() {
    // gets current timestamp
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); // What timezone you want to be the default value for your current date.
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: I do not know PHP, but have you tried `'date' => curdate()`? Seems to make more sense.

Comment: Inserted date is incorrect or empty?

Comment: yes i tried but i have no idea in syntax

Comment: undefined variable curdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the model method where you'll be inputting the date, load the "date" helper:

```
    $this->load->helper('date');
```

Or, if you're using it in more than one method, go ahead and load it in the class constructor.

Then, to insert the current date:

```
    'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now())
```

That should get you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in this string:

```
'date' => $this->input->post('date','curdate()')
```

Your framework (it's framework?) try to insert a value from post. And if this values is empty, inserts curdate(). In MySQL `NOW()` will insert current date or datetime.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in your syntax:

```
'date' => $this->input->post('date','curdate()')
```

should be

```
'date' => $this->input->post($this->curdate())
```

Alternatively, why not just do

```
'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

?